# Cancel background request for view when disappear

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, performselector

I have some view that is loading images in the background with

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImages:) withObject:nil];
```

Problem is that if I cancel this `view` while the method is processing, when it is done, it is trying to reload a `UITableView` that doesn't exist.

Should I cancel the background request when I cancel the view? how can I do that?

If I check for `nil` on the `table`, it's still show a pointer to the table even that i am in another page.

Comment: user despatch_que, then run in another thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`, because it would be better to use `NSOperationQueue` and the support that it (and `NSOperation`) offer for cancelling activity. Then, when the view is hidden just call `[operationQueue cancelAllOperations]`.

*(you obviously need to write the operation to consider if it has been cancelled...)*

That said, whatever `loadImages:` does in the background can still be cancelled by checking the status of the controller before it tries to use the result. You haven't shown the method contents, but that could be checking that a `BOOL` on the controller (say `isCancelled`) is `NO`, or that the controllers view has a superview.

Comment: Thanks, by checking a boolean on the view you mean that i will set a boolean to cancelled in the viewWillDisappear ,than check it ?  or how to check the if it has a parent view?

Comment: Yes, add a `BOOL` `@property`, set it in `viewWillDisappear` and check in the load method.

Comment: Well, you'll need to look into why (is the controller in a container?)

Comment: So I'd look first at the container and what it does to forward calls to children

Comment: btw what about this ?             [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(myFunction) object:nil];

Comment: That will only cancel if the selector hasn't been fired (so when using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) - not once the selector is running...

Answer (score 0):

You could check to see whether your table view is visible or not on screen before reloading it. You could write a helper method or even better a category on UIView that tells whether the given view is visible or not.

Declare isVisibleOnScreen Method on a category on UIView and implement it like this.

```
- (Bool)isVisibleOnScreen {

    CGRect viewFrame = self.frame;
    CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    return CGRectIntersectsRect(viewFrame, appFrame);

}
```

But a better way to do async work is using Grand Central Dispatch. It gives you more control over async work.

Comment: GCD gives little in the way of cancellation support, you should use the higher level `NSOperationQueue` API to get that.